# ionic with VoiceOver: how to read Chinese?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, accessibility, voiceover

I have created an app which requires accessibility for visually impaired people. VoiceOver works perfectly for the other Chinese apps in my phone. However, it only reads out in English but not in Chinese. How can I let VoiceOver recognize Chinese?

Is this a problem concerning the language of the HTML5 document? `<html lang="en" dir="ltr">`

What should I do in ionic? Or should I configure my Xcode project?

**Solution:**
replace `en` with `zh-HK` in `<html lang="en" dir="ltr">` for Cantonese.

Comment: are you using ionic native text-to-speech plugin?

Comment: @MaheshJadhav No, do I have to use it? I thought voiceover can do the job already.

Comment: can you tell me more about how the voiceover functions...what do you exactly do in your app?

Comment: voiceover is a builtin function in ios, reading out the content on the screen, also consider aria attributes in html elements. and I want 
 voiceover to read out the contents in the app for the visually impaired people https://www.apple.com/hk/en/accessibility/iphone/vision/

Comment: i guess you can even use zh-CN to be more specific to use Mainland China locale

Comment: Ok thanks,  The lang attribute does matter:) I have fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, two conditions need to be fulfilled in order to get content read out in the correct language, i.e. with the desired text-to-speech engine.

1. The screen reader needs to have a **text-to-speech engine** for the language of the content or app, in this case Standard Chinese or Cantonese. Since other Chinese apps on your phone are read correctly, this condition appears to be fulfilled.
2. The language of the content or the app needs to be **correctly identified**. This needs to be done using **language tags** that conform to [IETF BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47). According to this standard, Standard Chinese *should* be identified as `zh-cmn` or `cmn` and Cantonese as `zh-yue` or `yue`. However, not all browsers and screen readers may support these "newer" tags, so you may still need to fall back to the older tags `zh-CN` and `zh-HK`, respectively, which are still valid.